# My App crashes when a user types comma instead of dot?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

Okay so I'm in the process of creating a currency converter app.
When the user puts in the value he wants to convert, and he types "9,99" with a comma instead of a dot, the app crashes. 
How can I prevent that ?!

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func changeSteemTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let str = steemTextField.text
    if (str?.isEmpty)! {
        return
    }
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let steem = NumberFormatter().number(from: str!)?.doubleValue
    priceTextField.text = String(format: "%.4f", steem! * appDelegate.price_usd * rate)


}

@IBAction func changePriceTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let str = priceTextField.text
    if (str?.isEmpty)! {
        return
    }
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let price = NumberFormatter().number(from: str!)?.doubleValue
    steemTextField.text = String(format: "%.0f", price! / appDelegate.price_usd / rate)


    return
```

And this is the error message that pops up when you type comma instead of dot
[image: 1]
So my idea was maybe to implement a replacement code?
so that the system automatically replaces a dot with a comma once the user has typed it. 
This is the code I came up with, but why is it not working?

```
let aString = ","
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
```

Comment: What is the `rate`?

Comment: @MaxPevsner the rate depends on the currency, for example for dollars:    case "USD":
            label.text = "$  " + price_kind
            rate = 1.0

Comment: What is the issue "not working"? Post non-working code with `replacingOccurrences` included.

Comment: Check that `price`, `appDelegate.price_usd` and `rate` all have values and are not `nil` or 0.

Comment: my suggestion is that don't replace comma with a dot. You should display invalid input alert to alert the user that what he entered is something invalid. Because, what if the user want's to convert 9,999.99. You can't convert the comma here to a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app crashes because NumberFormatter (http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) can be set to only one locale at a time. In this case, it is set to US, therefore it expects that commas are used only for delimiting thousands, millions etc (eg. 9,999). Therefore, 9,99 is an invalid number representation.

You need to change str, and make sure that the changed value of str (one which replaces comma with dot) is taken as input. Note that this will fail for cases where someone enters the number 9,999.01 in European format (which is 9.999,01). You will explicitly need to invoke NumberFormatter for both locales in such cases, or write a more elaborate conversion logic.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, you need to change `let str...` to `var str` then change the value. This code works well:

```
var str = "99.5"

let aString = ","
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")

let price = NumberFormatter().number(from: str)?.doubleValue
```